# Theories for the algebras over monad

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I believe I have read somewhere that for *any* monad, the category of algebras over it can be presented as an equational theory, provided the operations can have infinite arity. I'm looking for a precise statement and proof of this proposition.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392419/reference-request-for-lintons-theorems-on-equational-theories